# Anime series where the Earth was suddenly surrounded by a kind of energy sphere in the sky, blocking anyone from leaving

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm sorry I can't give any details, but I just remember I once saw a Japanese anime series.

I think it was about a (future) Earth where the Earth was suddenly surrounded by a kind of (blue) energy sphere in the sky. How they were looking up and realizing it was blocking everything so they couldn't leave the planet anymore, or something like that. It was more about the figures and how they reacted. No monsters or super powers etc involved. Probably not even a villain!

And it was a kind of mirror/alternate world or something like that "up there". I know that sounds like the *Upside-Down* movie from 2012 but I'm sure it was an anime (and most likely a series and not a movie) and should be slightly older than that. But it wasn't really old. I remember it looked already CGI-enhanced so I'd say early 2000s.

I remember a dark, sad mood like it was changing the world to the worse, not the better. However my memory is not a really depressing story. Neither was it a dark sci-fi like *Final Fantasy* or whatever, more of a "mystery" instead.

If I would have to guess I'd say the (English) title was something like *Twin X* or something abstract like that. Maybe containing "sky" or "mirror" in the name?

Since I don't remember much of the story sadly - only a mood - I think it can't be a long story. Maybe one season perhaps. And its painting style was the typical "anime" one. If I had to guess, I would say the "normal" 2D paint style with slightly modernized backgrounds, so no 3D-generated characters etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly *Gilgamesh* (2003). A single season, 26 episodes.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/385/Gilgamesh):

> The half-divine King of Uruk, Gilgamesh, was considered but a paltry legend... until his majestic tomb was discovered in the Middle East. This imperial crypt drew scientists from across the globe to the land, and with that came recognition of their fame. In a joint effort, they built Heaven's Gate in pursuit of advancing human knowledge.
>
> One day, a group of terrorists driven by greed attack Heaven's Gate, causing an explosion within the facility for archaeological excavation. The resulting phenomenon had much more impact than anyone could have imagined.
>
> More specifically, it triggered the birth of supernatural beings. In the midst of this mess, two siblings by the names of Kiyoko and Tatsuya encounter mysterious men with supernatural powers who, despite the scientific crisis around them, claim the ability to restore good to the world. Nevertheless, these seemingly heroic and all-powerful creatures act under the rule of factions. Are they here to save the world, or destroy it?

While the above summary sounds way more "plot-oriented" than the "mood anime" you seem to remember, [the Wikipedia page of the source manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_(manga)) has the sky being engulfed in a sphere of sorts and, most importantly, names a "Twin X" event:

> Dr. Madoka goes down to Delphys, breaches all of the guards around it and comes into direct contact with Tear, causing **an immense explosion that blocks out the sky with a mirror-like layer.** This is considered an act of terrorism, as after the explosion, computers and wireless communications stop working, and the planet falls into war and famine. The human population is nearly wiped out. This occurs on October 10, so **the incident is called "Twin X"** (after the Roman numeral symbol for the number 10).

The trailer has the planet getting trapped, and the general grim setting:

---

Found with [IMDb's advanced title search](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/), with the following criteria ([2 results](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=tv_series&release_date=1992-01-01,2010-12-31&genres=animation,sci-fi&plot=mirror)):

- TV series
- Animation
- Sci-Fi
- Release date between 1992 and 2010
- Plot contains "mirror"

Comment: Wow, you are my heroe. Yes it looks like the one I had in memory. And you are right, the trailer looks different to what I had in memory. But I give it a try again and see it i's still as intense as it was when i was younger. Thanks a lot!